# Ubuntu 20.04 - How can i display the Dock on selected screens individually and Dock have different locations on each monitor (3 monitors)?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, monitor, dash-to-dock

[My attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6pD4.jpg)

- I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Nvidia GPU
- I have 3 monitors
- I use Dash to Dock and dconf.

As shown in the attached picture:

- Monitor number 1 is the main monitor.
- I only have 2 options: either show the Dock on all monitor or show the Dock on one of the monitor
- I am setting up Dock at monitor number 3, right Dock position.

My question:

- Is there a way to show MORE a Dock in monitor number 2 with the left position (not right same monitor 3).
- No need to display the Dock in the main monitor number 1.

Thank you for reading my question!